# Keeping a TableView updated with the Observer Pattern

Tags: java, javafx, observer-pattern

I'm writing a **JavaFX application**. I have a `TableView` with all entries from a database, populated as follows:

```
public class AdvertisementListController {

    @FXML public TableView<Advertisement> advertisementTable;
    @FXML public TableColumn<Advertisement, String> dateColumn;
    @FXML public TableColumn<Advertisement, String> productColumn;
    @FXML public TableColumn<Advertisement, String> vendorColumn;
    @FXML public TableColumn<Advertisement, Integer> priceColumn;
    @FXML public TableColumn<Advertisement, Integer> quantityColumn;

    // ...

     public void initialize() {
        dateColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("stringDate"));
        productColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("productName"));
        vendorColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("vendorId"));
        priceColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("price"));
        quantityColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("quantity"));

        // ...

        AdvertisementDAO advertisementDAO = new AdvertisementDAO();
        annunciTable.setItems(advertisementDAO.getAdvertisementObservableList());
    }
```

From another window of my application I can insert new entries in the table of the database. I'm new to GoF patterns, and I'm trying to implement here an **Observer pattern** in order to keep the table updated, but I don't really know where to start. **What's the subject here?** What's the Observer class?

Comment: I'm not sure, should I add the code relative to `Advertisement` class as well here?

Answer (score 2):

JavaFX is a framework that uses the Model-View-Controller (MVC) design pattern. If you do some research, you will realize that MVC also uses the `Observer` design pattern.

JavaFX took one step further in its support for the `Observer` design pattern. JavaFX has concept of `Property`, which is basically `Observer` design pattern. A `Property` object holds the value, and it can be used to observe for value changes. The base interface for `Property` (and `ObservableList` etc) is `Observable`.

Therefore, by using `Property` (and in your case `ObservableList`), you are already using `Observer` design pattern.

So in order to do it properly, these are what you need:

1. Make sure your `Advertisement` class stores `stringDate`, `productName`, `vendorId`, `price` and `quantity` as `Property`.
2. Instead of getting the `ObservableList` from `AdvertisementDAO` via `getAdvertisementObservableList()`, shift the `ObservableList` out, as a field of `AdvertisementListController`. You should instead alter the `ObservableList` whenever your data changes.
3. Depending on how the other window changes the data, you may also need to create your `ObservableList` with `FXCollections.observableArrayList(Callback)` overload.

Example:

```
public class Advertisement {
    private final StringProperty stringDate = new SimpleStringProperty();
    public final StringProperty stringDateProperty() { return stringDate; }
    public final String getStringDate() { return stringDate.get(); }
    public final void setStringDate(String s) { stringDate.set(s); }

    // Other properties
}

public class AdvertisementListController {

    @FXML public TableView<Advertisement> advertisementTable;
    @FXML public TableColumn<Advertisement, String> dateColumn;
    @FXML public TableColumn<Advertisement, String> productColumn;
    @FXML public TableColumn<Advertisement, String> vendorColumn;
    @FXML public TableColumn<Advertisement, Integer> priceColumn;
    @FXML public TableColumn<Advertisement, Integer> quantityColumn;

    private final ObservableList advertisements = FXCollections.observableArrayList(advertisement -> new Observable[] { advertisement.stringDateProperty() });

    public void initialize() {
        dateColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("stringDate"));
        productColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("productName"));
        vendorColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("vendorId"));
        priceColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("price"));
        quantityColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("quantity"));

        // ...

        AdvertisementDAO advertisementDAO = new AdvertisementDAO();
        advertisements.setAll(advertisementDAO.getAdvertisementList());
        advertisementTable.setItems(advertisements);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very clear. I still don't get the `stringDateProperty()` call inside the declaration of `advertisements` variable. Can you explain me it?

Comment: Moreover, using `StringProperty` instead of `String` forces me to change all usege of `Advertisement` attributes I make in my project... But I can't find an easy way to parse a `String` into a `StringProperty` (also being `StringProperty` an `abstract class`). Help!

Comment: @Robb1 "I can't find an easy way to parse a String into a StringProperty". What is wrong with the code in the answer? `private final StringProperty stringDate = new SimpleStringProperty();` and `stringDate.set(s)`?

Comment: @James_D Ouch, I was trying to instantiate it with `new StringProperty()`, thanks for making me notice the mistake :)